# c# func parameter not being used

Tags: c#, design-patterns, delegates, aop, func

I have a legacy app that logs the input / output of services. Currently, every method has the same lines to log the request and response objects. I would like to use AOP, but without adding any extra tool (Postsharp, Castle, etc), or wrap every service class into another class (ServiceWrapper).

In order to do that, I'm trying to create a Generic class that knows that it should log the request and response objects. Here's what I'm trying:

```
using System;

namespace ProxyTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var request = "request";
            var fooService = new FooService();

            ServiceProxy.Invoke(r => fooService.DoFoo(request), "abc");

            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    class ServiceProxy
    {
        public static void Invoke(Func<object, object> service, object request)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("input:" + request);

            var response = service(request);

            Console.WriteLine("output:" + response);
        }
    }

    class FooService
    {
        public string DoFoo(object a)
        {
            return a +  ": returning: Do Foo";
        }
    }

}
```

Although it's working, the "abc" string is just to compile the application, but it's not being used as the request parameter. If I remove that, the code does not compile. Am I missing something?

**UPDATE**

Changing to the following did the trick:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var request = "request";
        var fooService = new FooService();

        ServiceProxy.Invoke(r => fooService.DoFoo(r), request);

        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: Do you have access to services source? Is it WCF service?

Comment: "but it's not being used as the request parameter" - it is at the moment, within ServiceProxy.Invoke. It's not clear to me what you're asking here...

Comment: Why not call it like this `ServiceProxy.Invoke(r => fooService.DoFoo(r), request);` or just `ServiceProxy.Invoke(fooService.DoFoo, request);`

Comment: `ServiceProxy.Invoke(r => fooService.DoFoo(request), "abc");` Does `fooService.DoFoo()`returns a `Func<object, object>()`? You probably mean: `ServiceProxy.Invoke(r => fooService.DoFoo, request);`   _(DoFoo without the parameter)_

Comment: It seems like it would make more sense if your method was generic and actually returned the response `public static TResponse Invoke<TRequest, TResponse>(Func<TRequest, TResponse> service, TRequest request)`.  Then your `DoFoo` could take a `string` instead of an `object`.

Comment: thanks guys for the replys, that`s what I was looking for.

Comment: You should not post your solution into your question. Instead either post an own answer or mark that one which fits your problem as answer.

Comment: I voted up all of those that help me identify the solution. Unfortunately, all the useful answers were given as comments, that's why I didn't mark as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should call it like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var request = "request";
        var fooService = new FooService();

        ServiceProxy.Invoke(fooService.DoFoo, "abc"); // lose the DoFoo parameter.

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

You should pass the DoFoo as Func, instead of calling it. Also you should change the method signature to:

```
class FooService
{
    public object DoFoo(object a)
    {
        return a +  ": returning: Do Foo";
    }
}
```

Comment: Explain the -1?

Comment: You mean `ServiceProxy.Invoke(fooService.DoFoo, "abc");`, because what you have will not compile.

Comment: @juharr Thanks, didn't noticed it. fixed that

Comment: It's not the `DoFoo` that needs to change, it's the `ServiceProxy.Invoke` that needs to change for a generic signature like @HimBromBreere said. Otherwise I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

For this task you can just add logging behavior on dispatcher.
First, you create ServiceBehavior with such content:

```
public class ServiceLoggingBehavior : Attribute, IServiceBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        foreach (ServiceEndpoint endpoint in serviceDescription.Endpoints)
        {
            foreach (OperationDescription operation in endpoint.Contract.Operations)
            {
                IOperationBehavior behavior = new LoggingOperationBehavior();
                operation.Behaviors.Add(behavior);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
    }
}
```

Then you need to create operation behavior:

```
internal class LoggingOperationBehavior : IOperationBehavior
{
    public void Validate(OperationDescription operationDescription)
    {

    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
    {
        dispatchOperation.Invoker = new LoggingOperationInvoker(dispatchOperation.Invoker, dispatchOperation);
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, ClientOperation clientOperation)
    {

    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(OperationDescription operationDescription, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }
}
```

And finally create invoker for all methods on server side:

```
internal class LoggingOperationInvoker : IOperationInvoker
{
    private readonly IOperationInvoker _baseInvoker;
    private readonly string _operationName;

    public LoggingOperationInvoker(IOperationInvoker baseInvoker, DispatchOperation operation)
    {
        _baseInvoker = baseInvoker;
        _operationName = operation.Name;
    }

    public bool IsSynchronous
    {
        get { return _baseInvoker.IsSynchronous; }
    }

    public object[] AllocateInputs()
    {
        return _baseInvoker.AllocateInputs();
    }

    public object Invoke(object instance, object[] inputs, out object[] outputs)
    {
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        try
        {
            LogBegin();
            sw.Start();
            var response = _baseInvoker.Invoke(instance, inputs, out outputs);
            return response;
        }
        finally
        {
            sw.Stop();
            LogEnd(sw.Elapsed);
        }
    }

    private void LogBegin()
    {
        //you can log begin here.
    }

    private void LogEnd(TimeSpan elapsed)
    {
        //you can log end here.
    }

    public IAsyncResult InvokeBegin(object instance, object[] inputs, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        return _baseInvoker.InvokeBegin(instance, inputs, callback, state);
    }

    public object InvokeEnd(object instance, out object[] outputs, IAsyncResult result)
    {
        return _baseInvoker.InvokeEnd(instance, out outputs, result);
    }
}
```

If you want to log request, you can just serialize and log **inputs** variable in Invoke method. For response - just serialize and log **response** variable.

And finaly, most enjoyable part, just attach it like attribute:

```
[ServiceLoggingBehavior]
public MyService : IMyServiceContract
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Invoke`-method clearly asks for a `Func`-  and an `object`-parameter, so you have to provide both. No idea what exactly you´re expecting when you omit one of the params. I assume you want to make the `Func` to return the response created by a specific `request`-object. Furthermore it might be good idea to make your request- and response-arguments generic:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var request = "request";
        var fooService = new FooService();

        ServiceProxy.Invoke(r => fooService.DoFoo(r), request);

        Console.Read();
    }
}

class ServiceProxy
{
    public static void Invoke<TRequest, TResponse>(Func<TRequest, TResponse> service, TRequest request)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("input:" + request.ToString());

        var response = service(request);

        Console.WriteLine("output:" + response.ToString());
    }
}
```

The `Invoke`-call can further be simplyfied to `ServiceProxy.Invoke(fooService.DoFoo, request);`

Comment: You need to define the generic types on the method or the class for that to work.

Comment: What I need was remove the need to pass request object inside DoFoo and the same parameter to the Func.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the responses. I was able to achieve what I was looking for using:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var request = "request";
        var fooService = new FooService();

        ServiceProxy.Invoke(fooService.DoFoo, request);

        Console.Read();
    }
```

or

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var request = "request";
        var fooService = new FooService();

        ServiceProxy.Invoke(r => fooService.DoFoo(r), request);

        Console.Read();
    }
```